# Display specific table field (blog text) using Django

Tags: python, html, django

Hopefully a simple one, but I can't find what's wrong myself. I have a simple blog app, and I can display the posts titles, in a weird format, but can't pull through the posts body/text - all I get is a blank row.

> /models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

> /views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post

def index(request):
    posting = Post.objects.filter()
    context = {
        'posting':posting,
              }
    return render(request, 'posts/index.html', context)
```

> /templates/posts/index.html

```
<li>{{posting}}</li>
<li>{{posting.body}}</li>
<li>test text</li>
```

The output to the page is similar to (apologies not exact due to html formatting, but note blank middle line) :

QuerySet [Post: First Post>, Post: Second Post>, Post: Third Post>]>

test text

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your query from

```
posting = Post.objects.filter()
```

To

```
posting = Post.objects.all()
```

unless you are not filtering anything. and you are printing the whole object. To get the specific information print like this

```
{% for post in posting %}
    <li>{{post.title}}</li>
    <li>{{post.body}}</li>
    <li>test text</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `posting` is a queryset you need to loop over it in template.

Comment: yeah of course. thanks @Satendra for pointing that out.  I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you! This has worked - however if I use {{article}} I only get the titles - is there a way of printing everything or do I still have to specify individual fields as per the answer above?

Comment: Welcome. I don't see any article above, is it in any different model. Please accept the answer. It will help others facing the same problem

Comment: Apologies, I changed {{post}} to article. Thank you!

Comment: You need to specify individual field.